# Where is "showing the output of the 'ls' command vertically" documented?

Tags: ls, man, documentation

I [found out](https://suite101.com/a/linux-secrets-how-to-use-ls-effectively-a82135) it's possible to show the output of the `ls` command vertically using the `-1` switch:

> $ ls -1

But couldn't find it in the manual of `ls`. Is it a secret option?

Comment: `man ls` does tell: `-1     list one file per line`.  Info pages usually contain more information, try `info ls`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The manual is out of date with the program. Try `ls --help | grep -- '  -1'`:

```
  -1                         list one file per line
```

It is one of the last options described if you just do `ls --help`.

Comment: `/bin/ls` also gives output in columns, at least it does on my system. What is your `ls` aliased to?

Comment: Recent addition? OK, it's not in V7. But [2BSD had it](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2BSD/man/ls.u). The oldest GNU version I can find right now, [fileutils 3.12](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian-0.93R6/source/base/fileutils-3.12-2.tar.gz) had it, including documentation in the man page, and the ChangeLog goes back to version 1.0 in 1990 with no mention of it being added as a new option. I think it's always been there.

Comment: @timo, Thanks for the answer. Nice way to Explanation. Works for me.

Comment: Gotta love those ambiguous characters!

Answer (score 6):

As @Timo indicates `-1` is in the help, and @terdon points out the `-1` is documented in the manual for some version. `coreutils` 8.13 has that error in the man page, version 8.22 doesn't anymore.

In the [hacking guidelines](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/HACKING) for coreutils. It is specified that

> The man pages are generated from --help output, so
>   you shouldn't need to change anything under man/.

So there must be something broken in the conversion causing the similar `-m` to show up but not the `-1`. While building `ls` with the patch I proposed in [answer to @timo's question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112248/33055), the manual page for `ls` gets regenerated correctly and the relevant part reads:

> ```
>   -Z, --context
>           print any security context of each file
>
>   -1     list one file per line
>
>   -0     list files separated with NUL
>
>   --help display this help and exit
>
>   --version
>           output version information and exit
> ```

And without that patch, the -1 shows up in the manual as well. The `git log` shows no specific action to correct this. As recent as Sep 2013 `help2man`, which is used to generate the man pages, was updated. The `help2man` `ChangeLog` doesn't show a specific action either.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this will depend on your `ls` implementation but on my LMDE (basically Debian testing) I have:

```
$ man ls | grep -- '-1'
              across -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column  -1,
       -1     list one file per line
```

As well as (yes, it's the same output)

```
$ ls --help | grep -- '-1'
              across -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column  -1,
       -1     list one file per line
```

Comment: OS X man page for ls also shows the -1 option.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed. coreutils 8.13 has that error in the man page, version 8.22 doesn't.