# I would like to delete entire archive log except retain last generated archive log

Tags: linux, cron

I want to delete all the archivelog, But retain last generated archive log alone.

Currently I am using following which will delete entire/all the archive log and clear the directory itself.

```
find . -name "dbf*" -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But I want to retain the last generated archive log. How to do? What is the command I need to use for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot know that only one file per day is generated (your failing command would work in that case), you have to pipe the output of `find` in which you have a combination of the date-time-stamp of the file and the filename into `sort` and then exclude the final line with `sed` before splitting of the date-time-stamp (again with `sed`) and feeding the resulting names into `xargs  -0 rm`:

```
find . -type f -name "dbf*" -printf "%T@:%p\0" | sort -z | sed -z '$d' | \
       sed -z 's/[0-9\.]*://' | xargs -0 rm
```

As the filenames will start with `./` the second `sed` will only match up to the first ':' even though matching is greedy (`-printf "%T@:%p"` gives you something like  `1424765805.0206990940:./dbf_xyz`)

This should work with filenames with spaces and newlines as well, because the whole chain is using NUL terminated "lines"

Answer (score 0):

This works if you don't mind copying the most recent file to another directory while the rest are removed. Assuming you're current working directory is the one with the logs:

```
cp $(ls -Art | tail -n 1) /tmp \
&& rm -ri /path/to/logs \
&& cp /tmp/$(ls -Art /tmp | tail -n 1) ./ \
&& rm -i /tmp/$(ls -Art /tmp | tail -n 1)
```

Broken down:

- `cp $(ls -Art | tail -n 1) /tmp` copies the output of `ls -Art | tail -n 1` which should be the most recently modified file to the `/tmp` directory. You should probably create a new directory for this, instead of `/tmp`, or use something that you know won't have any other modified files.
- `rm -ri /path/to/logs` should remove all file descriptors in that directory.
- `cp /tmp/$(ls -Art /tmp | tail -n 1) ./` will copy the most recently modified file in `/tmp` back to your working directory.
- `rm -i /tmp/$(ls -Art /tmp | tail -n 1)` removes the file copied to `/tmp`.

Comment: The first bullet item will be fail on filenames that contain newlines.

Comment: That's something to consider. It also fails on file names containing a space. The path argument can be wrapped in double quotes `cp "$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)" /tmp`. I have not tested for newline files.

Comment: It doesn't work on files containing new line.

Comment: that is a common problem with parsing output of `ls`, has been tried to circumvent [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) and to solve [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112248/33055)