# Deleting files with spaces in their names

Tags: shell, quoting, rm, xargs

I am trying to delete all the files with a space in their names. I am using following command. But it is giving me an error

Command : `ls | egrep '. ' | xargs rm`

Here if I am using only `ls | egrep '. '` command it is giving me all the file name with spaces in the filenames. But when I am trying to pass the output to rm, all the spaces (leading or trailing) gets deleted. So my command is not getting properly executed.

Any pointers on how to delete the file having atleast one space in their name?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use standard globbing on the `rm` command:

```
rm -- *\ *
```

This will delete any file whose name contains a space; the space is escaped so the shell doesn't interpret it as a separator. Adding `--` will avoid problems with filenames starting with dashes (they won’t be interpreted as arguments by `rm`).

If you want to confirm each file before it’s deleted, add the `-i` option:

```
rm -i -- *\ *
```

Comment: You will DEFINITELY want to run this through an `echo` first, to guard from typos. Add `echo` at the front and it will print out all the files it's going to remove.

Comment: Anuj, the reason why this has the most upvotes is that because though `find` is powerful, sometimes you don't need to kill the chicken with a machine gun. UNIX administrators would generally not resort to `find` to (for example) "remove all files beginning with the letter A"... one would simply `rm A*`. Likewise to remove files containing spaces, rm can do the job. In other words, don't be fooled because space is invisible and is treated specially by the shell. Simply escape it, as Stephen Kitt has done, and you can think of it like any other character.

Answer (score 22):

I would avoid parsing `ls` output

Why not :

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -delete
```

No problem with `rm` :-).

Although this is recursive and will delete all files with space in current directory and nested directories, as mentionned in comments.

Comment: That will delete all the files with spaces in their names in the current directory and all sub-directories, with no more warning than `rm`...

Comment: (1) you can use `-name '* *'` instead of the regex; and (2) you can use `-print0 | xargs -0 rm -i` to address @StephenKitt's concern.

Comment: No need for `xargs`. Just use `-exec rm -i '{}' +`

Comment: Why avoid parsing ls, is there a specific reason or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: @Mhmd It's got more pitfalls than an 8-bit gaming console. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you want to avoid subdirectories, use `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '* *' -delete`.

Comment: `-regex` matches against the full path.  If there is a directory with a space in its name in the path, all its subdirectories and files would be deleted.

Comment: @Kusalananda All the files, but not the directories, no? `-type f` would skip those.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I just added the `-type f` after his/her comment

Comment: Ah, I see :) That doesn't fix the problem, though. The file `/path/with space/nospace.txt` would still be deleted.

Comment: @BenjaminW. fixed ?

Answer (score 8):

Look at this
Suppose name "strange file"

Solution one

```
rm strange\ file
```

solution two

```
rm "strange file"
```

solution three

```
ls -i "strange file"
```

you see the inode
then

```
find . -inum "numberoofinode" -exec rm {} \;
```

In case of very strange file names like

```
!-filename or --filename
```

use

```
rm ./'!-filename'
```

Comment: Working fine
rm "upload/image/catalog/Varanga/WhatsApp Image 2019-12-29 at 9.45.45 PM.jpeg"

Answer (score 5):

From `man xargs`

> xargs reads items from the standard input, **delimited by blanks** (which
>   can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or
>   newlines, and executes the  command (default is /bin/echo) one or more
>   times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard
>   input. Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.

We can (mostly) fix your initial command by changing the xargs delimiter to a newline:

`ls | egrep '. ' | xargs -d '\n' rm` (don't do this... read on)

But what if the filename contains a newline?

`touch "filename with blanks
and newline"`

> Because **Unix filenames can contain blanks and newlines**, this default
>   behaviour is often problematic; filenames containing blanks and/or
>   newlines are incorrectly processed by xargs. In these situations it is
>   better to **use the -0 option**, which prevents such problems.

`ls` [is really a tool for direct consumption by a human](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option/112126#112126), instead we need to use the `find` command which can separate the filenames with a null character (`-print0`). We also need to tell grep to use null characters to separate the input (`-z`) and output (`-Z`). Finally, we tell xargs to also use null characters (`-0`)

`find . -type f -print0 | egrep '. ' -z -Z | xargs -0 rm`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find . -name '* *' -delete
```

Comment: rm -- *\ *  seems better

Comment: Also, this was covered by [Kevin's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208140/deleting-files-with-spaces-in-their-names/208183#comment351655_208162) on solsTiCe's answer.

Answer (score -1):

To do it that way, you will need the `-Z` option of grep, and the `-0` option of xargs. But I would not do it that way (`ls` is not the right tool for the job, there are many problems in getting the computer to read its output).

See other answers for a better way.

---

Also

`ls | …` is equivalent to `ls -d *` and `echo * | …`

All of which have problems. Therefore don't use `ls` like this, use a solution from another answer.

Comment: Also `ls *` when pipes outputs the file names new-line delimited. `echo` (at  least some `echo` implementations) expands backslash sequences. `grep -Z` is for writing file names NUL-delimited when using `-l`, it won't help here. If you meant `-z`, that won't help either as most `ls` implementations lack an option to output file names NUL delimited. One could do something like `printf '%s\0' * | grep -z ' ' | xargs -r0 rm -f` though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think I have fixed it.