# How can I delete a file with spaces and quotes in the name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

How do I delete a file named `1 '2 3' 4 5`
in Linux? None of the methods I've used have worked.

Comment: Have you tried writing `rm 1` and pressing TAB? The tab completion is supposed to do all quoting for you, if the beginning of the file is unique. Using `zsh`, you can even tab-sycle through all possibilities.

Comment: If you could demonstrate some of those methods that didn't work, perhaps the answers here could teach you more about the *why*, and prevent future problems!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208140/deleting-files-with-spaces-in-their-names

Comment: "None of the methods I've used have worked."  Show us what those methods were, and we can help solve the problem.

Comment: [How to echo `single quote` when using single quote to wrap special characters in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187651/170373), [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373), [How to escape quotes in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30903/170373)

Answer (score 9):

You should "escape" both the spaces and the single quotes using `\`, so the command should be:

```
rm 1\ \'2\ 3\'\ 4\ 5
```

Or use double quotes:

```
rm "1 '2 3' 4 5"
```

In several shells, you can also use TAB completion (type `1` and then TAB to let the shell complete the rest of the file), and the shell will take care of using  appropriate quoting / escaping.

Comment: Or just single quotes: `'1 '\''2 3'\'' 4 5'`

Comment: You can also try to use globbing patterns for problematic characters, if the result is still unique: `'1 '?'2 3'?' 4 5'`

Comment: If it is hard to predict uniqueness, a safe method is interactive mode: `rm -i *1*2*3*4*5*` should not produce too many matches.

Comment: We don't need an exhaustive list of every conceivable way to generate the file name. The double quoted string is perfectly readable.