# How can I find the newest file in a directory that contains a certain string?

Tags: shell, files, grep, find

I have a need to search a certain folder for the newest created file and grep the contents for a pattern. I have had ok success so far using this command:

```
find /var/log/folder -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | tail -n1 | xargs grep 'string to find'
```

This does find the latest file that has the match but I am getting an unexpected line in stdout.

```
$ find /var/log/folder -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' |   sort | tail -n1 | xargs grep 'string to find'
grep: 2016-05-12+20:01:59.0570667340: No such file or directory
/var/log/folder/file:string to find
```

How can I change my command so it does not give me the "no such file or directory" line?

Answer (score 8):

`ls -1rt /path/to/files/ | tail -n1` will find the newest file in a directory (in terms of modification time); pass that as an argument to `grep`:

```
grep 'string to find' "$(ls -1rt /path/to/files/ | tail -n1)"
```

Comment: using -1art was returning "grep: .: Is a directory". I changed it to "ls -Art" and it works perfectly. So why was ls -1art was not working as expected?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: You find that `ls dir` and `ls dir/` do different things?  Not for me.

Comment: I do when I'm sleep-deprived and actually thinking of `rsync` and not `ls`.  The problem was that I had `-a` in my answer which was including `.` and `..`, which might end up being the most recently changed thing in a directory.

Comment: Ok I have a problem. This works but I have to be inside the folder where the ls is ran. If the command specifies an absolute path, why do I have to be inside that folder for it to work?

Comment: You can exclude directories with `ls`'s `-p` option (which appends a '/' to directory names) and piping into `grep -v '/$'` before piping into `tail -n 1`.  This works with at least GNU and FreeBSD's versions of `ls`.

Comment: Clever and efficient... +1 for using only `grep` and not `find` or `xargs`.

Comment: works on macos too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that is safe for names with whitespace:

```
find /var/log/folder -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -rz | sed -Ezn '1s/[^ ]* //p' | xargs --null grep string
```

How it works:

- `find /var/log/folder -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0'`

  This looks for files and prints their modification time (seconds) followed by a space and their name followed by a nul character.
- `sort -rz`

  This sorts the null-separated data.
- `sed -Ezn '1s/[^ ]* //p'`

  `sed -z` handles nul-character delimited lines and this prints just the name of the newest file
- `xargs --null grep string`

  This reads the null-separated file name and greps the string.

Comment: GNU `ls` really needs a `-0` or other NUL-delimiter option, like many other GNU tools (including `head` and `tail`)  have gained over the last decade or so....it's starting to become surprising when you find a GNU tool that doesn't have one yet.

Comment: @cas - that will probably [never happen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112125) (and for good reason imo).

Comment: It still would be nice to have a tool that offered ease of use,  like `ls` or  `ls -rt`, but that you could count on to work reliably with modern file names.