# Search for string in most recent file in directory

Tags: bash, text-processing, files

I wanted to `grep` a string from the most recent file in the current directory. By using the following command I am able to fetch most recent file but, not able to `grep` in that file only.

```
$ ls -lrth 

-rw-r--r--. 1 user pg_user 1712804 Jul 13 22:27 postgresql-2021-07-13_000000.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 user pg_user       0 Jul 14 00:00 postgresql-2021-07-14_000000.log
```

```
$ ls -lt postgresql-*.log | head -n 1 
-rw-r--r--. 1 user pg_user       0 Jul 14 00:00 postgresql-2021-07-14_000000.log
```

Now, I want to `grep` a string in `postgresql-2021-07-14_000000.log`

How I can combine both in one command to get output with `echo` on screen. Something like

```
$ls -lt postgresql-*.log | head -n 1 | grep "system is ready"
```

(only I know that there is still something missing here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the newest file in a directory that contains a certain string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282901/how-can-i-find-the-newest-file-in-a-directory-that-contains-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
grep -F 'system is ready' postgresql-*.log(.om[1])
```

The pattern `postgresql-*.log(.om[1])` consists of an ordinary globbing pattern that will match a selection of files in the current directory (`postgresql-*.log`), and a globbing qualifier that modifies the behavior of the globbing pattern (`(.om[1])`). The globbing qualifier is specific to the `zsh` shell.

The globbing qualifier used here makes sure that we only match regular files (`.`) and that the list of names resulting from the match is ordered by modification timestamp (`om`).  From the ordered list of matches, we then extract the first match only with `[1]`, giving us the name of the file matching the globbing pattern that is most recently modified.

If your interactive shell is not `zsh`, you may still use `zsh` to do this like so:

```
zsh -c 'grep -F "system is ready" postgresql-*.log(.om[1])'
```

Since you asked for a *script* to do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh

grep -F 'system is ready' postgresql-*.log(.om[1])
```

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Comment: -bash: zsh: command not found getting error when i try run you command

Comment: @AdamMulla If a tool that you need to use isn't available,  you may install it with your ordinary package manager.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me what you were missing is the `xargs` command. For your example you can use

```shell
ls -t postgresql-*.log | head -n 1 | xargs grep "system is ready"
```

The `xargs` command is used to execute command lines from standard input. In this case it will `grep` the file that is the output of the `head` command.

Note that for this to work you don't include the `-l` flag in the original `ls` so that the result of the head command is just the filename and not the extra information printed with `-l`.

If you are unfamiliar with `xargs`, there are plenty of good tutorials on how to use it that are just a quick internet search away.