# grep string from 1 to specific line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am working on Linux and I'm running the following:

```
$ ls -t postgresq*.log | head -n1 | xargs grep "ALTER USER"  
< pg_user 2021-07-15 05:03:41.609 EDT > LOG:  statement: ALTER USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'JUly@#12' valid until '2021-07-20';
```

But I only want to grep the string below:

```
ALTER USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'JUly@#12' valid until '2021-07-20';
```

Comment: if it is a fixed schema pipe your grep to: awk -F ":" '{print $5}'

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-o` (from `man grep`):

```
$ man grep | grep -P -A1 -- '^\s+-o'
       -o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Since `-o` will make `grep` print only the matched part of the line, you can just search for `ALTER USER.*` to match everything from `ALTER USER` to the end:

```
$ ls -t postgresq*.log | head -n1 | xargs grep -oP 'ALTER USER.*'
ALTER USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'JUly@#12' valid until '2021-07-20';
```

Note that [parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is generally not a good idea, but it is probably safe in your case since these log files should have simple names.

Answer (score 0):

Using teh `zsh` shell and `sed` to find and modify the line you're looking for:

```bsh
sed '/ALTER USER/ s/.*statement: //' postgresq*.log(.om[1])
```

The globbing pattern `postgresq*.log(.om[1])` was explained in some detail in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658303/116858) to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/658295/116858). In short, it expands to the name of the most recently modified regular file  whose name matches `postgresq*.log`, or it generates an error if no names matches the pattern.

The `sed` expression

```
/ALTER USER/ s/.*statement: //
```

will find any line that contains the string `ALTER USER` in the given file, and then delete everything from the start of that line up to the space after the string `statement:`.