# Shell syntax for redirecting arguments?

Tags: shell, xargs, arguments

If I want to redirect not the stdio but as arguments the output of a program , should I use xargs?

For example, I do `ls` and I want the filenames to be arguments to the next command rather than an input stream.

Is there a good example of what I'm talking about? This example is superficial but illustrates what I mean: use the output from `ls` as arguments to `cat` for displaying the contents of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [do **not** parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  There are many reliable ways of getting file names but [`ls` is *not* one of them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112126/53604).

The following uses the shell's globbing to generate file names and passes a nul-separated list of them to `xargs` which runs them through `cat`:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 cat
```

---

I understand that the point of this was to demonstrate files->xargs.  Otherwise, of course, unless there are too files to fit on a command line, the above can be replaced with:

```
cat *
```

#### Being more selective

Both `ls` and `printf '%s\0' *` will display all of a directory's contents, including its subdirectories.  If you want to be more selective, say, including regular files but not subdirectories, then, as cas suggests, `find` is better tool:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

Or:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} +
```

`find` has many useful options.  See `man find` for details.

Comment: Note that `cat *` can cause an arguments list too long error.

Comment: @cuonglm Very true.  I updated the answer to mention that case.

Comment: what if I need pass output of `ls -t | head -1` to another command? based on your answer, I worked out `printf '%s\0' "$(ls -t | head -1)" | xargs -0 gvim` (needed the double quotes for filename having spaces).. tested a few cases, but not sure if this can open latest modified file for all sorts of filenames..

Comment: @spasic If your file names don't contains any special characters, then try `gvim "$(ls -t | head -1)"`.

Comment: that seems to work even for special characters like space/quotes/newlines, same as the command with xargs.. I think both are equivalent

Comment: +1. `printf "%s\0" *` will also output directories, symlinks, device nodes, named pipes and sockets.   `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0` is better.   Use `find -L ...` if you want to follow symlinks (i.e. treat symlinks to files as if they were files)

Comment: @cas Very good.  I just added two `find` examples to the answer.