# Why has ls never had a parsable option implemented?

Tags: ls, history

So we all know you [shouldn't parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/237982) for many reasons, mostly due to filenames allowing almost every character.  However why has nobody been able to overcome this in an implementation of ls?

Many commands have a command line argument that will output parsable text to stdout, often csv format. Now I know filenames can have commas but so can csv files, that is a simple fix using double quotes.  I guess another issue would be that filenames could also contain double quotes, but I still refuse that the open source hivemind couldn't find some solution to this.  What is preventing someone from implementing a parsable option for ls?

Comment: Don’t the GNU `ls` `-b` and `-Q` options count?

Comment: It's because of a curse: whoever dares printing filenames in a parsable format is damned to an eternity of suffering.

Comment: Some feel that `ls` is only intended for "human consumption"; related; see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option?)

Comment: @StephenKitt: if the filename has c style escapes in it these options wont help you actually parse it in a usable manner

Comment: @jesse_b Is this a dupe of your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/is-there-a-reason-why-ls-does-not-have-a-zero-or-0-option?

Comment: @Kusalananda: yeah it seems so

Comment: @jesse_b yes they will, the escapes will escaped themselves.

Comment: Why haven't YOU done it?  How do you think FOSS things happen, anyway?