# How to make the kernel section 9 manpages which document functions, data structures, and headers?

Tags: kernel, man, documentation

The kernel [sources](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/) contain *functions* and *data structures* which are documented, for instance in [`panic.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/panic.c#n62):

```
/**
 *  panic - halt the system
 *  @fmt: The text string to print
 *
 *  Display a message, then perform cleanups.
 *
 *  This function never returns.
 */
void panic(const char *fmt, ...)
```

Instead of going through the sources every time, it would be useful to view those APIs as *manpages* and leverage this existing documentation framework.

---

How do you install/make the *kernel section 9 manpages*(`/usr/share/man/man9`) which document the aforementioned functions and data structures?

Comment: Care to share the distro you're using?

Comment: Why are you so sure there are always man pages (especially updated) for every release?

Comment: @mdpc  why wont a well maintained kernel will not have any man pages,i think my question is valid

Comment: "You need to install xmlto " seems like the place to start, no?

Comment: @Bralam updated the surprise :(

Comment: Yeah, it recommends dblatex which (as the name suggests) needs a LaTeX and thus TeX install. TeXLive is big; sorry. You could try not installing the recommended dblatex package; not sure if its needed for the kernel scripts.

Comment: I think you should refine this to not use the word `install` since the answers are all about making, and the second you hit on installation you should specify the distro (wihch you don't).

Answer (score 8):

The content is [parsed directly](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-doc-nano-HOWTO.txt) (see also [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DocBook/Makefile)) from the *source* .c files<sup>1</sup>:

> In order to provide embedded, 'C' friendly, easy to maintain, but
>   consistent and extractable documentation of the functions and data
>   structures in the Linux kernel, the Linux kernel has adopted a
>   consistent style for documenting functions and their parameters, and
>   structures and their members.
>
> The format for this documentation is called the kernel-doc format. It
>   is documented in this Documentation/kernel-doc-nano-HOWTO.txt file.
>
> This style embeds the documentation within the source files, using a
>   few simple conventions.  The scripts/kernel-doc perl script, some SGML
>   templates in Documentation/DocBook, and other tools understand these
>   conventions, and are used to extract this embedded documentation into
>   various documents.
>   [...]
>
> The opening comment mark "/**" is reserved for kernel-doc comments.
>   Only comments so marked will be considered by the kernel-doc scripts,
>   and any comment so marked must be in kernel-doc format.

Which means only such formatted comments can be extracted this way and that you could leverage the [`kernel-doc`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kernel-doc) *Perl* script used by the `make` process:

```
kernel-doc [ -docbook | -html | -html5 | -text | -man | -list ]
  [ -no-doc-sections ]
  [ -function funcname [ -function funcname ...] ]
  c file(s)s > outputfile
```

and therefore that you are not limited to the *mandocs* [target](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/README):

> After installation, "make psdocs", "make pdfdocs", "make htmldocs", or
>   "make mandocs" will render the documentation in the requested format.

There are also driver specific [text files](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation) in the kernel repository/source. More generally, their *Linux man-pages project* (*man1* through *man8*) is [available](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) for download. On a last note kernel.org also maintains some [output](https://www.kernel.org/doc/) documentation.

---

<sup>1. The kernel is not the only case where such a technique is used to generate manpages. GNU *coreutils* is one such other case; most of its manpages are [generated](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/HACKING) using the output of `command --help` the content of which is in the *usage* function the utility source file ( [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112247/44370) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147311/44370) ).</sup>

Comment: make mandocs throws me `Makefile:19: /Documentation/DocBook/media/Makefile: No such file or directory`

Comment: yes i have it but `Documentation/` is not present in `/`its present in `/lib/modules/3.2.0-57-generic-pae/build/`

Comment: @Shyam Those are the files for the modules etc., like the link to _text files_ in my A. You can maybe try `./scripts/kernel-doc -man ./**/*.c >mydoc` from the sources top directory and see if you can't put in all directly into one file by parsing the sources directly.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu,

```
apt-get install linux-manual-3.2
```

or similar (pick the correct version). There is also another documentation package

```
apt-get install linux-doc
```

but this is html.

Comment: this doesnt show kernel api's documentation

Comment: @Shyam Example?

Comment: On Arch(Bang) I have: _linux-manpages_ 3.14-1 which contains the section 9 manpages! Thank you! An example is _kcalloc.9.gz_. There is about 4000 of them...

Comment: @Faheem Mitha treid of viewing the `man alloc_register_region` but said no manual entry are docs different from man pages ??

Comment: @FaheemMitha i dont think kernel's low level api's are available with linux-doc !

Comment: I don't have a `linux-manpages-*` in my repo, did they rename it?

Comment: @EvanCarroll What distribution are you using?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Ubuntu `apt-cache search linux-manual` returns nothing

Comment: I asked another question much more specific to what I was looking for after I found the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/454030/3285

Comment: @EvanCarroll `apt-cache search linux-manual` returns `linux-manual-4.9` and `linux-manual-3.2` on Debian stable stretch/stable.

Comment: Not sure what to say, it's not in Ubuntu http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/

Comment: @EvanCarroll 4.9 is only in stretch. And I was mistaken about 3.2. It's not in stretch - it's left over from an earlier installation. A search online gives a hit for wheezy (Debian 7), two releases ago.

Comment: Wasn't what I was personally looking for anyway =) All good though

Answer (score 4):

[Download the kernel source code](https://www.kernel.org/) and in the source dir execute

```
make mandocs
```

After the man documents have been made, execute

```
make installmandocs
```

This will install the manual pages into `/usr/local/man/man9/`. Now you can view man pages by typing `man <api-name>`, or if you are editing in `vim` just press <kbd>K</kbd> over the API name.

Comment: But the makefile in `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38/Makefile` does not have rule `mandocs` neither `installmandocs`