# Kernel man pages, make: *** No rule to make target 'installmandocs'

Tags: kernel, make, man, documentation

As a follow up to this question, [*How to make the kernel section 9 manpages which document functions, data structures, and headers?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148426/3285). I downloaded the kernel source code and in the source dir execute

```
make mandocs
make installmandocs
```

This installed the manual pages into `/usr/local/man/man9/`. Now you can view man pages by typing man , or if you are editing in vim just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> over the API name.

I downloaded the kernel source and try run make mandocs.

> make: *** No rule to make target 'installmandocs'.  Stop.

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt-get install linux-doc`?

Comment: linux-doc installed already. but no man page for kernel function. Let know any other way to find kernel function

Comment: or if your web browser has such feature, nagivate to https://manpages.debian.org/ and add it as search engine . search example `kcalloc.9`

Comment: you could borrow the "prepackaged" manpages from Debian. They are only available for a few kernel versions. latest seen: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-manual-4.9  (caveat: [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) valable both ways... )

Comment: I tried to clean this up @user3227126 you had the same error a few times and the formatting was pretty foobarred good luck with it, I gave you an upvote. I also removed the connection to Ubuntu/Debian because you're just building from source. Seems like to be a problem with the kernel's Makefile or your use of it (unrelated to Ubuntu/Debian)