# Installing man pages for section 9 (kernel routines)

Tags: linux, kernel, man, documentation

I use [kernel.org docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/) to read about kernel functions. Now I am trying to make possible reading manuals for kernel-mode functions, such as `printk` with `man 9 printk`. The section 9 is used for this purpose: from `man man` section descriptions:

> 9 - Kernel routines [Non standard]

Running `make mandocs` at `/usr/src/linux/` throws this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'mandocs'.  Stop.
```

(I think `mandocs` is obsolete or was removed). I cannot find man9 packages on my Gentoo GNU/Linux system. Also, I tried to install those manpages on Debian 11 virtual machine, but it fails too.

How can I install/make/download those non-standard manpages for kernel functions to be able to run `man printk` to get docs without having to search documentation online or browsing header files?

I know that similar questions were already asked ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148426/how-to-make-the-kernel-section-9-manpages-which-document-functions-data-structu) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443645/kernel-man-pages-make-no-rule-to-make-target-installmandocs)), but they are deprecated (no `make mandocs` now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During May 2017, Linux kernel documentation [migrated to use ReST instead of DocBook (commit)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/Documentation/Makefile?h=v5.10.61&id=415008af321999f502c281cae617037b3738d127). During the final steps of that migration, the `make mandocs` target was [removed from kernel Makefile system (commit)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/Documentation/Makefile?h=v5.10.61&id=18afab8c1d3c2a463eece561e9f15a1704b5eff9).

Apparently nobody has missed the manpage format enough to submit patches for a process that would build the kernel functions man pages from the new ReST documentation source format.

Note that you can run `make htmldocs`, `make latexdocs`, `make pdfdocs` or `make epubdocs` to get a local version of the kernel documentation in HTML, LaTeX, PDF or EPUB formats.