# Looking up docs for C header files?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, man, documentation, header-file

On Ubuntu if I type `man 2 time` I get,

```
NAME
       time - get time in seconds

SYNOPSIS
       #include <time.h>

       time_t time(time_t *tloc);
...
```

I get that this works because `time` is the name of the function, but sometimes I don't know the name of the stuff, I just remember the file. Like say I know what I want is in `stdint.h`, but I can't remember the identifying thing -- or even worse it's not a function (as is the case when I wanted the docs for `ptrdiff_t`), how do I find the docs on this header file?

At the bottom of `man 2 time` it says,

> **COLOPHON** This page is part of release 4.15 of the Linux man-pages project.  A description of the project, information about reporting bugs, and the latest version of this page, can be found at https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.

The [kernel.org has the page for `stdint.h`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/stdint.h.0p.html). What package has these man pages so I can peruse offline? Why do I have the page for `time.h`, but not for `stdint.h`?

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148426/how-to-install-make-the-kernel-section-9-manpages-which-document-its-functions-a

Comment: @slm I actually think this is a duplicate of that one. I'm going to delete and ask for a refinement.

Comment: Actually let's dupe it because this specifically mentions headers and it's probably worth having it around since I didn't know headers were section 9.