# What Debian/Ubuntu package has the documentation for the standard C headers?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, c, documentation, header-file

On the back of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148426/3285), but Debian/Ubuntu specific that has C-standard library headers like ([taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library))

```
assert.h , complex.h , ctype.h , errno.h , fenv.h
, float.h , inttypes.h , iso646.h , limits.h , locale.h
, math.h , setjmp.h , signal.h , stdalign.h , stdarg.h
, stdatomic.h , stdbool.h , stddef.h , stdint.h , stdio.h
, stdlib.h , stdnoreturn.h , string.h , tgmath.h , threads.h
, time.h , uchar.h , wchar.h , wctype.h
```

I'm wanting to know where I can find the documentation for them packaged, so I can run

```
man stdint.h
```

Currently using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are **SECTION 7 Miscellaneous** and provided by

> `manpages-posix-dev` Manual pages about using a POSIX system for development. These man pages describe the POSIX programming interface, including these two sections
>
> - `7` = POSIX header files (with 7posix extension)
> - `3` = POSIX library calls (with 3posix extension)

Install them with `sudo apt install manpages-posix-dev`

You can see which headers are documented by the package with,

```
apt-file list manpages-posix-dev |
  sed -e'/\.h\./!d' -e's,.*\/,,' -e's/\.7posix\.gz//'
```

Currently that list is,

```
aio.h , arpa_inet.h , assert.h , complex.h , cpio.h
, ctype.h , dirent.h , dlfcn.h , errno.h , fcntl.h
, fenv.h , float.h , fmtmsg.h , fnmatch.h , ftw.h
, glob.h , grp.h , iconv.h , inttypes.h , iso646.h
, langinfo.h , libgen.h , limits.h , locale.h , math.h
, monetary.h , mqueue.h , ndbm.h , net_if.h , netdb.h
, netinet_in.h , netinet_tcp.h , nl_types.h , poll.h , pthread.h
, pwd.h , regex.h , sched.h , search.h , semaphore.h
, setjmp.h , signal.h , spawn.h , stdarg.h , stdbool.h
, stddef.h , stdint.h , stdio.h , stdlib.h , string.h
, strings.h , stropts.h , sys_ipc.h , sys_mman.h , sys_msg.h
, sys_resource.h , sys_select.h , sys_sem.h , sys_shm.h , sys_socket.h
, sys_stat.h , sys_statvfs.h , sys_time.h , sys_times.h , sys_types.h
, sys_uio.h , sys_un.h , sys_utsname.h , sys_wait.h , syslog.h
, tar.h , termios.h , tgmath.h , time.h , trace.h
, ulimit.h , unistd.h , utime.h , utmpx.h , wchar.h
, wctype.h , wordexp.h
```