# Factoring a grep out of a grep | sed stream or writing grep in sed?

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file like:

```
file.foo
file2.foo
file.bar
file3.foo
```

Now I want to return only lines that end with `.foo`, but I want to rename all occurrences of `file` with `blag`. In this case that means skipping over `file.bar` entirely. How do I go about doing it **with just sed**? Essentially what I'm doing currently is:

```
grep '\.foo$' input | sed -e's/file/blag/'
```

But I would like to cut the grep out.

[This question is roughly based on a pipeline I made for this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454031/3285)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get `grep` out of my pipeline to `sed` by using `!d`

```
sed -e'/\.foo$/!d' -e's/file/blag/' ./input
```

Answer sourced from [this forum post](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/31674-how-do-i-negate-sed-match.html)

Comment: Because of the lack of anchoring, this would output a line with `thefile.food` as `theblag.food`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yep, fixed -- this is MVP (minimal problem to show an example). As a side note the actual use case needs to be unanchored (link in question)

Answer (score 3):

Or, in mirror form, turn default-printing off, do the replacements, then only print lines you want:

```
sed -n  's/file/blag/; /\.foo$/p' < input
```

Or, filter on the desired lines *first*, then do the replace-and-print:

```
sed -n '/\.foo$/ { s/file/blag/; p }' < input
```

Comment: I think I would go with my own answer because the one that I think answers the title and is what I was looking for is to filter the desired lines *first*. If there is no implementation differences, I think `sed -n '/\.foo$/ { s/file/blag/; p }'` is more difficult to follow than `sed -e'/\.foo$/!d' -e's/file/blag/'` But you still have the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Select lines that end in `.foo` and execute a substitution for only those lines:

```
sed '/\.foo$/{s/file/blag/}'
```

Testing:

```
$ echo $'file.foo\nfile2.foo\nfile.bar\nfile3.foo' | sed '/\.foo$/{s/file/blag/}'
blag.foo
blag2.foo
file.bar
blag3.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/\(file\)\(.*\)\(\.foo\)/blang\2\3/p' input.txt > output.txt
```

(writes to output file)

OR

```
sed -i 's/\(file\)\(.*\)\(\.foo\)/blang\2\3/' input.txt
```

(in-file replacement)