# What does the "ls -1" command do?

Tags: shell, osx, ls

In my current directory, I execute the command:
`ls -1` and it gives a list of the current directory contents.

In the same directory, I repeat the command: `ls` and it gives me the same result, with perhaps a different formatted output.

Finally, I try to find out about the available commands by typing `ls --help` and the output is:

```
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

It looks like the last option is `1` (#1). Can someone explain what the `ls -1` does and how it's different to the standard `ls` command?

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410550/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112125/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111975/ .

Comment: **check if your ls command is also aliased**

Comment: I know Suse aliasies `ls` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` for example, and also has an environment variable "LS_OPTIONS" and they use some options I do not care for so I manually comment out any aliasing of the `ls` command; if this is happening under the hood on you without you knowing then `ls` output can sometimes not make sense and be confusing (i.e. why is this happening)  `ls -1` should simply output one column *but only if some other option is not overriding or preventing it from happening*

Comment: `ls -1` is often used by shell scripts to ensure there is minimal information and one file per line to make processing file names easy.

Comment: @Mark indeed, but [parsing `ls` is a bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440), and `ls -1` is the default when the output isn’t a terminal (which is the case when the output is supposed to be processed in a script).

Comment: I agree parsing`ls` is a bad idea, and you are right; forgot about that being the default when STDOUT is not a terminal.

Comment: try `info ls` or `man ls` if `ls --help` does not help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, the formatting of the output is the only difference between `ls -1` and `ls` without any options.

From [the `ls` manual on my system](http://man.openbsd.org/ls):

```
 -1      (The numeric digit "one".) Force output to be one entry per line.
         This is the default when output is not to a terminal.
```

This is also a [POSIX option to the `ls` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ls.html).

The manual for `ls` on your system is bound to say something similar (see `man ls`).

Related:

- [is piped ls the same as ls -1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410550)

Answer (score 9):

`ls -1` lists one file per line. By default, when it’s outputting to a terminal, `ls` lists files in columns, whose number varies depending on the length of the file names and the available space on screen.

To find this kind of information, `man ls` works better than `ls --help`. (This is true for most commands.)

Comment: *`man ls` works better than `ls --help`*  Especially so as `--help` is a non-portable non-POSIX extension.

Answer (score 0):

`man ls` contains (searched via `/-1<Enter>`)

```
   --format=WORD
          across -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column -1, verbose -l, vertical -C
```

`ls -1` triggers the single column mode. `ls` by default displays its content in multiple columns, just like the `column` command line tool would.

Comment: The user is on a BSD system, judging from what `ls --help` produces.  Their manual would unlikely contain `--format`.